# How to build a connection string in oledb

Tags: c#, vb.net, connection-string, oledb

Currently, I'm using the following connection string

```
ls_connstr=@"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Persist Security  Info =True;
             User Id=test2;Initial Catalog=eApproval; 
             Data Source=192.168.100.94;Password=123456789;
             Connect TimeOut=1020;Max Pool Size=20;Pooling=True;"
```

but this is giving me an error msg which is:

> "Login failed for user test2. Invalid connection string attribute "

Here test2 is my username.

Comment: To what database are you trying to connect?

Comment: I ma using Sql databse

Comment: If you're connecting to SQL Server then you should use a `SqlConenction` rather than an `OleDbConnection` if you possibly can.  Either way, go to [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) to get the appropriate connection string format.

Comment: actually  it is an older version of sql 2008 and oledbconnection is used

Comment: Are you sure about your password? I have tested this particular connection string and it works unless I type a wrong password and then I get the error message about the invalid attribute

Comment: yeah i am  sure about my password

Answer (score 0):

Use like this;

```
Provider=sqloledb;Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;
User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```